# Should users keep reputation earned via plagiarized content?

Tags: discussion, reputation, plagiarism

In my time on SO, I have flagged dozens of posts on SO for plagiarized answers and they have been deleted mods by in response. All fine.

But one thing I have noticed is that reputation earned by such answers is not deducted in some cases because the answer is older than 60 days on
the day it was deleted. [I understand why the rep isn't deducted](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/):

> First, if you’ve contributed something worthwhile to the site, you should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets deleted. “Worthwhile” here is defined as,
>
> A score of 3 or greater
>      Visible on the site for at least 60 days
>
> In fast-changing professions, there should be no shame in contributing valuable information just because it eventually goes out of date – and there shouldn’t be a penalty for deleting it when it does. Naturally, editing to bring an answer up-to-date is preferable – but if someone else already posted a good answer with current information, you should be able to remove yours and keep the reward for the time it was useful.

which is a fair policy. But does reputation earned by plagiarization meet the criteria?

I think that the above policy was designed with good intentions so as to not punish genuine contributors who posted answers in good faith which might have become out-of-date/obsolete/wrong/SO-policy-change, etc later on.

With plagiarized content, the "contributor" *knows* it's a blatant cheating. So should they keep reputation earned that way once they have been confirmed as plagiarized & deleted?

To me, it feels like a "loophole in the system" (something that was designed for a good purpose is "accidentally" exploited).

Comment: Why stop at plagiarism - I'd go so far as to suggest that the protection for rep gained from old answers should only apply to *self-deleted* answers. I don't see a reason that someone should be able to preserve rep from **any** answer that needs to be deleted by a moderator.

Comment: Who in his right mind is going to answer "Yes" to this question?  Okay, dammit, I'll have to do it then.  Of course it is "Yes", the system is not designed to cover all possible ways that users exploit the site.  Bummer, it is not a big deal.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about this too much. When we're talking about a really significant amount of rep, ♦ moderators typically ask the CMs to invalidate the rep. When we're talking about an account that engages in a lot of plagiarism, that account is likely to spend a lot of time suspended or just get deleted outright. (Most serial plagiarists end up getting their accounts deleted, so any rep is moot.)

Comment: @EdCottrell I fully agree that this is not a serious problem - I just wanted to know the thoughts of the wider community. Seems it's been discussed before and came to a similar conclusion.